# How can I use createPendingResult inside fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, onactivityresult

I have a user dialog which is created from a fragment. The user can make a choice and I want this choice to be delivered to fragment's `onActivityResult`. To do so, I use `createPendingResult`. This method works fine for an activity, but for a fragment I need to call `getActivity().createPendingResult`. This causes the result to be delivered to parent activity instead of fragment!
It is kind of complicated for me to call fragment's onActivityResult from parent activity's `onActivityResult`.
Is there another way?

This is the code for the dialog:

```
public static void selectChoice(final Context c, final PendingIntent callback) {
    (new AlertDialog.Builder(c))
         .setTitle(title)
         .setSingleChoiceItems(items, index, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             try {
                 callback.send(c, STATUS_CHANGED, 
                               new Intent().putExtra(EXTRA_CHOICE, which));
             } catch (CanceledException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }                   
             dialog.dismiss();
         }
    }).show();
}
```

This is the call I make inside the fragment:

```
selectChoice(getActivity(), getActivity().createPendingResult(
    REQUEST_DIALOG, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
);
```

This is fired in the parent activity, but not in fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if ( requestCode == REQUEST_DIALOG && resultCode == STATUS_CHANGED ) {
        ...
    }       
}
```

Comment: Provide code for clarity, please.

Comment: Please, post some code.